# extract the time with respect to 0 value, find the multiple working hours in a day, in MongoDB array operations

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Explanation :
I want to extract the `time start`  and `end time` from this `data`. whenever 0 comes then it means it will be an end time and if the next value is greater than 0 then its new time starts and I want to split the document into multiple documents whenever new time will start that value is >0.

**The use case is**: User is doing working multiple times in a day, not a complete day (9:00 to 17:00). for example, the user is doing working (9-10,  11-12,  15-16). so we have to split the documents for 9-10, 11-12, 15-16. whenever the value is 0 then it means the User is not doing working, it will be time end. when the value is > 0 then it means the user starts working again.

```
{
    "data": {​
"2020-09-04T12:18:41Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T12:18:42Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T14:59:50Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T14:59:59Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T15:00:00Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T15:00:01Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T15:05:00Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T15:05:01Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T15:40:00Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T15:40:01Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T16:00:00Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T16:00:01Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T16:30:00Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T16:30:01Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T16:52:50Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T16:52:51Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T18:10:00Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T18:10:01Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T18:35:00Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T18:35:01Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T18:59:00Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T18:59:01Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T19:00:00Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T19:00:01Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T19:30:00Z": 0,
"2020-09-04T19:30:01Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T19:52:50Z": 1,
"2020-09-04T19:52:51Z": 0
}​
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a bad design when you use actual values as field names. Anyway, you could use an aggregation pipeline like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   // Transform to array
   { $set: { data: { $objectToArray: "$data" } } },
   // Sort the date values, bear in mind fields have an aribitary order, they are not sorted!
   { $unwind: "$data" },
   { $sort: { "data.k": 1 } },
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: { k: "$data.k", v: "$data.v" } } } },
   // do the actual logic
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$data",
               initialValue: [],
               in: {
                  $cond: {
                     if: { $eq: ["$$this.v", 0] },
                     then: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                           "$$value",
                           [{
                              k: "$$this.k",
                              v: "$$this.v",
                              group: {
                                 $cond: {
                                    if: { $ne: [{ $last: "$$value.v" }, 0] },
                                    then: { $ifNull: [{ $last: "$$value.group" }, 0] },
                                    else: { $add: [{ $ifNull: [{ $last: "$$value.group" }, 0] }, 1] }
                                 }
                              }

                           }]
                        ]
                     },
                     else: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                           "$$value",
                           [{
                              k: "$$this.k",
                              v: "$$this.v",
                              group: { $last: "$$value.group" }
                           }]
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // Split into documents per group
   { $unwind: "$data" },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$data.group",
         start_time: { $first: "$data.k" },
         end_time: { $last: "$data.k" }
      }
   }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ru50N5Uc0o_)

Comment: thanks for the answer : I agree with you the design of the document is really bad. I try to solve this in different way can you check this. and can answer how I can element from the array if is it followed by 0 only.  [if0isFollowedBy>=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69129058/remove-0-values-if-0-is-followed-by-1-from-arrays-in-mongodb)

Comment: Would be more or less the same. Just the first 4 stages could be skipped.

Comment: but how I can check the condition? if it followed by 0 or not inside the array? also, remove the elements from `time_start`