# remove 0 values if 0 is followed by >=1 from arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In `data_start` if 0 is followed by >=1 in the array then remove the 0 from the `data_start` , also remove the element from `time_start` array accordingly.

```
{
  "data_start": [
    1,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    1,
    0
  ],
  "time_start": [
    "2021-09-04T12:18:42Z",
    "2021-09-04T14:59:50Z",
    "2021-09-04T14:59:59Z",
    "2021-09-04T15:00:00Z",
    "2021-09-04T15:00:01Z",
    "2021-09-04T15:05:00Z",
    "2021-09-04T15:05:01Z"
  ]
}
```

Output Document will be :

```
{
"data_start": [
    1,
    1,
    0,
    1,
    1,
    0
  ],
  "time_start": [
    "2021-09-04T12:18:42Z",
    "2021-09-04T14:59:50Z",
    "2021-09-04T14:59:59Z",
    "2021-09-04T15:00:01Z",
    "2021-09-04T15:05:00Z",
    "2021-09-04T15:05:01Z"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $let: {
               vars: {
                  val: "$data_start",
                  prev: { $concatArrays: [[null], "$data_start"] } // shift values by one element 
               },
               in: {
                  $map: {
                     input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$$val" }] },
                     as: "idx",
                     in: {
                        $cond: {
                           if: {
                              $and: [
                                 { $eq: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$val", "$$idx"] }, 0] }, // is 0
                                 { $eq: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$val", "$$idx"] }, { $arrayElemAt: ["$$prev", "$$idx"] }] } // is equal to previous
                              ]
                           },
                           then: null,
                           else: {
                              data_start: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$val", "$$idx"] },
                              time_start: { $arrayElemAt: ["$time_start", "$$idx"] }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$data",
               cond: "$$this"// -> removes null's from array
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Maybe you have to fine-tune the condition and/or reverse the loop, i.e. `input: { $range: [{ $size: "$$val" }, 0, -1] }`

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7MZ01bMgkI2)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little ugly in Mongo but possible, the strategy for us would be to first iterate over the array and calculate the indexes of the items we need to remove, once we have those we will iterate over the two arrays again and update them and finally we remove the temporary calculated values, like so:

Note that to do this purely in Mongo you will need to be on v4.2+ as we need to use [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) if you're using a lesser version then you will have execute this logic in code.

```
db.collection.updateOne(
{},
[
  {
    $set: {
      tmpField: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $zip: {
              "inputs": [
                {
                  $reverseArray: "$data_start"
                },
                {
                  $range: [
                    {
                      $subtract: [
                        {
                          $size: "$data_start"
                        },
                        1
                      ]
                    },
                    0,
                    -1
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          initialValue: {
            prev: null,
            indexesToRemove: []
          },
          in: {
            prev: {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$$this",
                0
              ]
            },
            indexesToRemove: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value.indexesToRemove",
                {
                  $cond: [
                    {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            "$$value.prev",
                            1
                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          $eq: [
                            {
                              $arrayElemAt: [
                                "$$this",
                                0
                              ]
                            },
                            0
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    [
                      {
                        $arrayElemAt: [
                          "$$this",
                          1
                        ]
                      }
                    ],
                    []
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data_start: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $zip: {
              "inputs": [
                "$data_start",
                {
                  $range: [
                    0,
                    {
                      $size: "$data_start"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $in: [
                  {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      "$$this",
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  "$tmpField.indexesToRemove"
                ]
              },
              "$$value",
              {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$$this",
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      time_start: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $zip: {
              "inputs": [
                "$time_start",
                {
                  $range: [
                    0,
                    {
                      $size: "$time_start"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $in: [
                  {
                    $arrayElemAt: [
                      "$$this",
                      1
                    ]
                  },
                  "$tmpField.indexesToRemove"
                ]
              },
              "$$value",
              {
                $concatArrays: [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$$this",
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "tmpField"
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nofgLNpgf6r)

Comment: Using three times `$reduce` + `$concatArrays`, may cause performance issued if you have bigger data, see [Performance issue for $reduce vs. $map](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-53503).

Comment: interesting ... definitely worth considering at scale.

Comment: No idea, I made this experience only with `$concatArrays`